# Monthly Average on Daily Statistics

Tags: sql

I have a table of call center agents (daily statistics), which is stored by an agent per day.

I would like to get an monthly average for all agents, so I can compare monthly statistics with, however my current attempt will show only daily averages during the month as opposed to the average for the whole month:

```
select
  Convert(Date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0),0),
  AVG(CallsAnswered)
FROM
    dbo.AvayaD_Agent_Stat
GROUP BY
    Convert(Date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0),0)
```

Appreciate any help you can provide (or need clarification), and thank you!

---

**EDIT:**
Hopefully this helps a bit, I realize the above isn't great at explaining what I'm shooting for.  What I am looking to produce is a Average of the sum of agent statistics for the month. (if that is worded correctly)

For example if I have 2 agents who both work 10 days, one takes 10 calls a day, the other takes 20 calls a day.  Currently that shows as 15 calls using the query I have above.  I'd like that to be presented as 150 calls (300 total calls/ 2 agents).  My problem with this however is I can't put a static amount of days/ agents as it is always changing.

Including a larger snip of the table as requested.

```
 select Date,
    AgentLogin, 
    CallsAnswered
    from dbo.AvayaD_Agent_Stat

Date    AgentLogin  CallsAnswered
2014-08-11  1005    21
2014-08-12  1005    21
2014-08-13  1005    23
2014-08-14  1005    18
2014-08-15  1005    16
2014-08-18  1005    25
2014-08-19  1005    44
2014-08-20  1005    17
2014-08-21  1005    25
2014-08-22  1005    12
2014-08-25  1005    23
2014-08-26  1005    32
2014-08-27  1005    24
```

Comment: I just tested your code with some dummy data and it is returning averages per month. Potentially there is something else that I haven't seen. Could you supply a sample set of data and the table structure?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  I'm not sure what "average for the whole month" really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the average per agent for the entire month, sum up the total for the month and then divide by the number of agents:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0),
       SUM(CallsAnswered) / COUNT(DISTINCT AgentId)
FROM dbo.AvayaD_Agent_Stat
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)
```

Note I also removed the final `convert()` on your month calculation.  It is redundant.

Comment: That looks perfect! Didn't consider dividing by Count(distinct)  Thank you very much!